# How to restrict outboound connection to a URL rather than a IP address, on an Azure virtual network?

Tags: azure, networking

I have a Virtual Network which I have setup to deny all outbound traffic except to a single URL in which I want it to connect to.

This host has a single URL but multiple, and often changing, Ip addresses.

What's the best way for me to add a rule that allows all traffic to a URL instead of an Ip Address?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean" a single host", It is a VM?

Comment: No not a VM, I mean a single public URL.

Comment: What is a rule? Do you mean NSG associated with that Vnet?

Comment: Yes I mean the NSG associated with that Vnet.

Comment: Problem is NSG works at TCP/UDP level where there are no URLs, only IP addresses.

Comment: But is there anyway I can setup a proxy or something? Surely there's some way of allowing access to a URL rather than IP addresses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

I created a function app through the azure portal.

Added a proxy, set the "/" as the Route template, and the URL as the backend url as per below.

[image: Azure proxy]

I then set the outbound rule to allow the virtual ipaddress of this function app.

I then just pointed my vm at the proxy instead of the real URL.